# How can you refresh UI labels without constantly querying the backend?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, parse-platform, refresh

the App I am developing is very reliant on updating the UI efficiently, as users can . the current method I have in place is to call the NSTimer method scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, every one second, calling a function that essentially performs a backend Parse query, checking if any data has been changed. is this the only / most efficient way of refreshing the UI data? Ideally I'd love a method that automatically responds to backend changes rather than manually checking every second to see if there are changes?
Help much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at silent notification. Rather than checking the back end every second for any new data, wait for a notification that says "hey new data" and then download the data.

Comment: @Poql Yes , you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can [send a push notification](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/JavaScript) from a Cloud Code [afterSave method](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#save-after).

Answer (score 0):

As [Poql](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857555/poql) said - Rather than checking the back end every second for any new data, wait for a notification that says "hey new data" and then download the data.

**For automated system** there is nothing like so. `"Automatically"` have to be defined by you. So basically you can create some `Custom Notification` which will call a method for you , get the respected data and update it .

**For UI update** I think `uiview.tag` is made for that. Store your all `tag information` somewhere , if something is changed get the respected tag and perform a refresh.

Comment: thanks guys, v helpful. i have actually wondering if there was a way to allow information to be communicated initially without the backend. so for example, if one user clicks a button, that updates every users UI accordingly. then at the point that user interaction is disabled and they cannot update the UI any further, then data is saved to the backend? this probably isnt possible i know

Comment: Yes this could be done. You can manage it through your `Data Structure` . But it depends what the UI update Actually means. As far as my idea its something like `Whatsapp's Last Seen` Feature but a bit changed. Here other user UI is depend on my activation.

Comment: essentially if you can imagine that there is an image being scored by a group of users. everytime one user scores, that affects the UILabel denoting the average. after a given period of time, I want this label to be saved in the backend. so what I am asking I suppose is how can I convey this information on everyone's UI and update it accordingly without having to constantly save and query from the backend?

Comment: Well without backend there is no way. Backend could anything suppose `Game Center` or `iCloud` or `Parse` etc. Other work can be done as we suggested but the logic will be yours. Just get data somehow (from web api or any other way) , use it accordingly. But checking on time basis is not good. It took your resources a lot. First confirm that data is changed , get the changed data (or whatever you need) , make a mechanism that update your UI.

Comment: ok thanks, time checks will be ditched. that's annoying, surely there has to be a way for users to communicate on the platform without querying the backend. like some sort of messenger SDK, without the messenging aspect but instead a scoring feature?

Comment: i didnt know one but it would be good. You can try with iOS default message app and create one on based on that. If i ever need i will create a different DS for that which hold all my running games (or session).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using local data store of parse, Certainly it's not the best solution every second checking.It drains your daily requests of parse.It might be good if you are using local datastore.